# How to get the image's "real" path using Image Picker?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to move a file to another path using the package image_picker in my app, to make that I need the "real" path of the selected image, but I get a path from my app's cache. Can someone tell me how I can get the path that the selected image occupies on the device?

My code:

```
Future<void> _performMultimediaPicker({bool isVideo}) async {
  PickedFile _pickedFile;
  if (isVideo) {
    _pickedFile = await imagePicker.getVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  } else {
    _pickedFile = await imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  }
  if (_pickedFile != null) {
    print(_pickedFile.path);
  }
}
```

Result in console:

```
/data/user/0/com.example.file_safe/cache/image_picker497203239088344241.jpg
```

Comment: What's wrong with using that path?